# Codeigniter: Limit Logged-In User's Access to Controller

Tags: javascript, php

CODEIGNITER:
How can I limit the logged in user's access in controller functions. Because it can be accessible by putting the function name in the ADDRESS BAR right?

I'm looking to make that there is a group of functions for USER1 and there is also another different group of function for USER2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use sessions to check limit user access on certain functions

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Thank you so much brother! I forgot sessions geez. haha! Anyway thanks again and Jah bless brother!